# jQuery attaches events not sticky in user control

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-controls

have a user control for a specific calculation scenario hosted in a web-forms pages that has an AJAX panel that surrounds the user control.  Each user control has some JQuery that attaches events to the buttons within the control.

On first page load, everything works as i would expect but once the page has done a partial postback the events are lost because the jQuery associated with the control does not re-run.

By moving the jQuery to the pageLoad of the hosting page it does run but this messes up the encapsulation as it would mean all the jQuery code for every scenario would have to be in the hosting page.

Is there any way to force the code associated with the control to re-run?

Comment: It should work even if event attached at partial control. Can you unfold code?

Comment: Thanks Amit,  unfortunately i had to move on and put the code in the page load rather than the control load!  Definitely the control load only fires a single time until a full repost of page is done!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was move the script tag to the bottom of the page!!  I had used the defer attribute which works differently in IE10 and IE11!!